# What are the rules for resolving symbols as macros vs. function parameters?

Tags: variables, clojure, macros, shadowing

I was surprised to find that [alpha-conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B1-conversion) is not safe in Clojure:

```
Clojure> ((fn [o] (o 3 2)) +)
5

Clojure> ((fn [or] (or 3 2)) +)
3

Clojure> ((fn [def] (def 3 2)) +)
java.lang.RuntimeException: First argument to def must be a Symbol
```

(I expected all three snippets to evaluate to 5).

What's the rule(s) for symbol resolution when shadowing and macros, and special forms are involved?

I'm using the version on [Try Clojure](http://tryclj.com/).

Comment: Another example: `(let [def 1] def)` ==> okay vs `(let [def +] (def 2 3))` ==> error.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot shadow special forms, according to [the documentation](http://clojure.org/evaluation):

> A Symbol is resolved:
>
> - If it is namespace-qualified, the value is the value of the binding of the global var named by the symbol. It is an error if there
>     is no global var named by the symbol, or if the reference is to a
>     non-public var in a different namespace.
> - If it is package-qualified, the value is the Java class named by the symbol. It is an error if there is no Class named by the symbol.
> - **Else, it is not qualified and the first of the following applies:
>
>   1. If it names a special form it is considered a special form, and must be utilized accordingly.**
>   2. A lookup is done in the current namespace to see if there is a mapping from the symbol to a class. If so, the symbol is considered to
>        name a Java class object. Note that class names normally denote class
>        objects, but are treated specially in certain special forms, e.g. '.'
>        and new.
>   3. If in a local scope (i.e. in a function definition), a lookup is done to see if it names a local binding (e.g. a function argument
>        or let-bound name). If so, the value is the value of the local
>        binding.
>   4. A lookup is done in the current namespace to see if there is a mapping from the symbol to a var. If so, the value is the value of the
>        binding of the var referred-to by the symbol.
>   5. It is an error.

And I'm not sure, but I interpret this passage (from the same page) to mean that you cannot shadow macros, either:

> Macros are functions that manipulate forms, allowing for syntactic
>   abstraction. If the operator of a call is a symbol that names a global
>   var that is a macro function, that macro function is called and is
>   passed the unevaluated operand forms. The return value of the macro is
>   then evaluated in its place.
>
> If the operator is not a special form or macro, the call is considered
>   a function call.

Answer (score 3):

The first two both evaluate to 5 for me (Clojure 1.4 in Eclipse / Counterclockwise REPL). I suspect there is a bug in Try Clojure if you are getting 3.

You should be able to locally shadow over both function and macro names (though it often isn't a good idea since it can result in some subtle and confusing bugs!).

The third won't work because `def` is a [special form](http://clojure.org/special_forms). Special forms get special treatment from the Clojure reader and/or compiler, so you can't shadow them.

Comment: the first two evaluate to 5 for me as well (1.4, lein repl)

Comment: Hmmm, maybe the [docs](http://clojure.org/evaluation) need an update about macros?  Seems to me it implies that macros can't be shadowed.  Not sure, though.

Comment: You should be able to shadow macros; tryclojure and 4clojure use an incorrect macroexpander that doesn't allow shadowing, because implementing one that is both correct and secure is particularly hard.